# pac pcf push does not update component in dynamics

Tags: components, microsoft-dynamics, pcf, pac

I've been successfully building and updating PCF components for the last two months and all the sudden the command to push the component to dynamics does not seem to update any of the changes I make (not in the current project or in previous ones).

Does anyone know if there is something going on at MS why the pac pcf push command does not update components anymore?

I have the latest pac version and the npm build command runs successfully.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same problem with "pac pcf push" not updating the changes anymore so I ended up reverting to pac CLI version 1.16.6 and that fixed the problem for me.